# How to make output from array to listbox?

Tags: arrays, powershell, listbox

I'm trying to make some GUI using SAPIEN PowerShell Studio.  My goal is to display list of users with creation dates, and so far I have this:

```
$arrLastCreatedUsers = @(Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Created | Select-Object name,Created | Sort-Object Created);

$listbox_LastCreatedUsers.DataSource = $arrLastCreatedUsers;
```

If i do it in cli, output looks like what i wanted to see, but when it comes to output to listbox, every string looks like that:

```
@{name=name1; Created=Sun, 10.10.2012 16:09:40}
@{name=name2; Created=Sun, 10.10.2012 16:09:43}
@{name=name3; Created=Sun, 10.10.2012 16:09:46}
@{name=name4; Created=Sun, 10.10.2012 16:09:48}
@{name=name5; Created=Sun, 10.10.2012 16:09:50}
```

It isn't what i want to see, of course... so what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using objects as data, you need to specify which member will be displayed. If you don't do that, it will use `$obj.toString()` to get the value that it shows in the list(which is what you have atm.). Try this:

```
$listbox_LastCreatedUsers.DisplayMember = "name";
```